# Problem installing nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 17.10 lenovo 320e?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 17.10, lenovo

I have a Lenovo 320e laptop, it comes with integrated *Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)* GPU and dedicated *Nvidia GeForce 940MX* GPU.

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 17.10 on this laptop, all the other stuff is working great except the graphics card, it was using internal instead of dedicated.

So I tried to install the drivers following [this tutorial](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux), but it did not work. It installed the driver but Ubuntu was still using the integrated GPU.

Here is the output when I run `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

`dpkg -l | grep nvidia` reports:

```
ii nvidia-384              384.98-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.1   amd64   NVIDIA binary driver - version 384.98 
ii nvidia-opencl-icd-384   384.98-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.1   amd64   NVIDIA OpenCL ICD 
ii nvidia-prime            0.8.5                        amd64   Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime 
ii nvidia-settings         387.22-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.1   amd64   Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

The System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers panel looks like this:

[image: additional drivers]

If you go to the [Nvidia Linux x64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver page (Version:  384.98)](https://nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/126577/en-us), you can see my card in the list of supported products.

I also tried blacklisting the `nouveau` kernel module, it did not work either.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see nvidia-370 in that PPA? Which one is installed? Check with `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`.

Comment: nvidia-384 is installed